# How do I change the name of my project

Tags: scala, sbt

### Project File

From a text editor, create a project file
`project/build/Project.scala` with the following contents:

```
import sbt._ 
class Project(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info) {}
```

### Package

Make a jar out of your work

```
> package
```

Creates a jar file:

```
target/scala-2.8.1.final/default-f94d1d_2.8.1-0.1.jar
```

but I'd prefer something like:

```
target/scala-2.8.1.final/myProjectName_2.8.1-0.1.jar
```

So how do I adjust the above project file, such that I get a more meaningfully named jar artifact?

Answer (score 3):

You should provide a name for your project (and an organisation) theses informations will be used to create the maven artifact:

*For SBT 0.10 / 0.11 you can take a look at the wiki which describe in great details how to create configuration file for your project.*

https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Settings

**It looks like you are using 0.7 - You should really think about upgrading to version 0.11**

https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Migrating-from-SBT-0.7.x-to-0.10.x